# How to insert/update/Delete record from a single view in mvc

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I a trying to insert/update/delete record using a single view page. but unable to find any solution so far. If any one have any example or any information about it than please help me.

I have table something like that

```
<table id="responsive-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
            </th>                    
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.age)
                </td>                            
                <td>                               
                    <a id="btnEdit" data-id="@item.TimeSheetID " class="action-icon clsEdit"><i class="pms-edit"></i></a>                                
                    <a id="btnDelete" data-id="@item.TimeSheetID" class="action-icon clsDelete"><i class="pms-delete"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> **Note** do not want to use modal popup and another div for hide show just want to insert and update record in a table row.

Here I want to use this above table for insert/update and delete but not getting any idea for it and also want to put some input text here for manage `name and image`. so it anyone have any information or link than please share it.

Answer (score 1):

**1. HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    MVCDbContext _db = new MVCDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_db.Model1.ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult add(Model1 objmo,int?id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            Model1 objdata = _db.Model1.Find(id);
            objmo.fname = objdata.fname;
            objmo.lname = objdata.lname;
            return View(objdata);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult add(Model1 obj)
    {
        if (obj.Aref == 0)
        {
            _db.Model1.Add(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            Model1 objdata = _db.Model1.Where(x => x.Aref == obj.Aref).FirstOrDefault();
            objdata.fname = obj.fname;
            objdata.lname = obj.lname;
        }
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult delete(int? id)
    {
        _db.Model1.Remove(_db.Model1.Find(id));
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

```html
2. Index.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<mvc_crud_dropdown.Models.Model1>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "add")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Aref)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lname)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aref)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "add", new { id=item.Aref  }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Aref })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: This is about the controller but what about index page how i should manage my input controls over there

Comment: Not working and giving error like `The view 'add' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:`

Comment: @user2963609 : this view is strong type view you can use input controls by adding another normal view.

Comment: How can i do like that which you are telling. i don,t have any idea